# HostBuilder in Unit Test: HostContext.Configuration.GetSection returns value null

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm trying to use the `HostBuilder` class in an `MsTest` test case in the following way:

```
        [TestMethod]
        public  void SomeTest()
        {
            var builder = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                {
                    config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true);
                })
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    var section = hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("AppConfig");
                    Assert.IsNotNull(section.Value, "Appconfig sections was not loaded");
                });
            var host = builder.Build();
        }
```

So I've an `appsettings.json` file that is added to the `config` object.

**Problem:** When calling `hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("AppConfig")` `section.Value` is `null` (`Assert` is fired up). If I debug the code I can see that `hostContext.Configuration` has an `JsonConfigurationProvider` which has parsed the appropriate values defined in `appsettings.json`.

**Environment:** netcoreapp3.1

**Update1:** I've uploaded the source code to [Github](https://github.com/moerwald/HostConfigurationTest).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thx.

Comment: Do you have an `appsettings.json` file in your test project? Make sure that in the file properties of `appsettings.json`, select either "Copy if newer", or "Copy always".

Comment: Yes it is in the project, otherwise ‚AddJsonFile‘ would throw an exception.

Comment: And also copied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you were able to resolve this, but I ran into a similar problem as well! How I was able to resolve it was that upon inspection of appsettings.json properties, it appears that the default action for this file was never. Hence, when the project was built in the target folder the appsettings.json file was never copied over. Changing this setting to "copy always" or "copy if newer" solved it and now I get the updated json file in the target executing folder.

The code you have up there seems to be fine -- mine is very similar.

To test if this is the problem indeed you have, change

```
config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true);
```

to

```
config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false);
```

This will force the app to fail if the file doesn't exist. this was also how I found the problem after an embarrasingly long amount of time.

To check the properties of this file, right click on it on the solution explorer and select properties. In the default VS 2019, the properties panel is right below the solution explorer.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was running the app from a cmd instance, so basically it was a **different working directory** and hence the `appsettings.json` couldn't be found. What helped was `cd`ing into the directory first.

I used this to always load the config from the base directory and throw if it's missing:

```
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
{
    config.SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory);
    config.Sources
        .OfType<Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationSource>()
        .Where(x => x.Path == "appsettings.json")
        .ForEach(x => x.Optional = false);
})
```